# Pytorch is it possible to chain model prediction with two dataloaders

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

In my training schedule, the process of loading data with `__getitem__` takes quite a lot of time. It's an image-to-image problem (2x upscaling). I followed the classic approach and I get `input` images and `target` images from the same data loader. Prediction of my model also takes some time. The scenario which could help me to speed up the process of training would be to create two separate data loader, the first one `input_dataloader` for input images and the second one `target_dataloader` for target images, and use them as follow:

1. Load only input image from `input_dataloader`.
2. Predict the upscaled images.
3. While the model is predicting the images load the target image from `target_dataloader`.

In this scenario, I could overlap the expensive data loading with the computation of my model, quite similar to [`non_blocking`](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-we-set-non-blocking-to-true/38234) but on a data loader level.

Are there any PyTorch modules that I could use to implement such behavior?

Comment: Are you using num_workers > 0 when you define your `DataLoader`s? If so then the next batch should already be being loaded asynchronously while your model processes the current batch.

Comment: @jodag good point, I wasn't aware how `num_workers` value affects the process of loading the data.

Comment: But sure, in general you can add a worker process with its own target dataset, have the input dataset return an index into the target dataset rather than the target itself, and pass the index to the target dataset (which is now off-main process), returning the result with a queue. Note that you'll have to use torch.multiprocessing and passing CUDA tensors between processes can get a bit tricky